# Не могу найти правильный подход к изучению Java и разработки под Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

я начинающий программист, изучаю Java и хочу изучать разработку под Android. Проблема в том, что я не могу найти правильный подход к изучению, и меня это сбивает с толку. Правильней будет : изучать Java походу разработки Android приложения или прочекать всю теорию Java,а затем начинать что-то разрабатывать в Android Studio?

Comment: Стабильно 2 вариант

Comment: но просто на это может уйти много времени, и все равно всего не запомнить, особенно, если без практики. А так , если походу разрабатывать и изучать то,что нужно - было бы в разы лучше. Разве нет ?

Comment: Могу посоветовать ресурс для начала - javarush...сам с них начинал. И теория и практика

Comment: да, но там надо платить.

Comment: @Влад практиковаться сначала придётся с учебными примерами на PC.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev так я так  и хочу. Есть видео курс, по которому идет изучение разработки Android приложений в Android Studio. Можно смотреть эти курсы,повторять то,что делают по видео, потом изучить этот код, разобраться в нем, и походу изучать Java.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а что вы можете посоветовать ?

Comment: @Влад посоветую взять учебник по Java для начинающих, прочитать, разобраться с разработкой простых консольных программ, потом разобраться с разработкой десктопных программ с графическим интерфейсом, потом прочитать более подробный учебник, после него попробовать разрабатывать более сложные приложения для PC, а уже через полгода-год такой практики брать учебник по Android'у.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а можете посоветовать литературу ? Вот я сейчас читаю Шилдта "Java 8. Руководство для начинающих"

Comment: @Влад Шилд неплох, но для старта лучше всего "Изучаем Java" Кэти Сиерры и Берта Бейтса, а потом "Философию Java" Эккеля.

Comment: Пора уже на Kotlin переходить.

Comment: Влад, плохо конечно что вы не написали ничего о текущем уровне знаний.  Не известно как хорошо вы знаете базовые вещи типо циклов, условий. А так, считаю, из Java вам нужно знать всё что входит в Java core, этот список везде может быть разным, но в общем в него входит весь базис. После хоть глазком прочите о принципах SOLID, важнее то почему они появились, что они решают. А то как их использовать придет позже. После начинаете с сайта стартандроид. И не стоит жалеть денег на вложение в себя. Ментор может дать за 2 минуты ту инфу , до которой вы сами можете дойти за неск дней

Comment: Это не обязательно репетитор, а человек к которому можно сходить с накопленными за пару недель вопросами.  И много платить не надо, но и долго сидеть не приходится на непонятном.

Comment: @Turalllb уровень знаний - ходил на курсы Introduction Java, по сути введение в джаву, база. Знаком с циклами,условиями, переменными, инкапсуляция, конструкторы,насследование и т.д. В общем база.

Comment: И самое главное. Лучше заниматься каждый день по 2 часа , чем только на выходных по 18 часов.  На много лучше. В разы.

Comment: Согласен, если не начать самому кодить, то на книгах далеко не уедешь без практики.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Сначала нужно прочитать любую книгу по java или пройти курс. Советую **"Изучаем Java" Кэти Сьерра, Берт Бэйтс.**

Советую ее, потому что она максимально **быстро** вводит в курс дела, читается легко, с картинками, то что нужно для начинающих. Примеры в книге делайте только, если не понимаете код этого примера. Эта книга дает азы java, которых хватит для android. Там есть раздел swing. Пропускайте его. Это 12 и 13 глава. 15 и 18 тоже можете пропустить, а можете и прочитать для развития. В андроиде все это не используется.

Ее можно быстро прочитать, получить основы. Я прочитал за месяц примерно, но читал всю.

Далее начинаете изучать android. Главные критерии ресурса: постоянные обновления и известность. Android очень быстро меняется, поэтому всегда нужно изучать самые свежие ресурсы. Все что старее 2016 лучше не смотреть. Есть три хороших ресурса:

- startandroid
- книга Android для профессионалов
- курс от гугл на Udacity

Вот плотно изучайте эти ресурсы и параллельно делайте какое-то приложение. Вот и все.

Алгоритм можете быть такой: берете за основу udacity и делайте все по нему. В книгу смотрите, если не понимаете ничего на английском, или хотите решить какую-то специфическую задачу.

Startandroid  - на сайте есть отличные пошаговые руководства по новым библиотекам, например: room, dagger , rxjava. В будущем они вам очень понадобятся, потому что сейчас они уже почти везде используются.

P.S. *Почему не стоит углубляться в java?*

Потому что android довольно однотипный и все нюансы java вам не нужны. Вам главная база, чтобы понимать, что происходит в коде. А нюансы вы уже будете изучать на своих приложениях в андроиде

P.S.S. *Мое личное мнение*

Старайтесь долго не застревать на обычных активити, фрагментах, интентах. Core Android большой и его можно долго изучать. Достаточно пару приложений на 2-3 экрана. Не делайте огромных приложений,которые вы будете разрабатывать по 3 месяца.Это будет тормозить ваш прогресс.

Стремитесь понять архитектурные паттерны и современные библиотеки, которые облегчат вам разработку больших приложений и помогут устроиться на работу. Вот примерный стек:

*Архитектура:* MVP, MVVM, SOLID, Clean Architecture, Architecture Components

*Библиотеки-боссы(долго изучать):* Rxjava**2**, Dagger

*Библиотеки-ништяки:* Retrofit, Okhttp, ButterKnife, Room, Picasso, GSON. Их изучать можно сразу же, потому что они облегчат вашу жизнь.

Comment: а знания XML  тоже должны быть, чтобы разрабатывать приложение, в    книге тоже это затрагивается?

Comment: @Влад после Head first java можно сразу head first android. xml - не язык, ничего не нужно учить, всё гуглится по необходимости)

Comment: @Maxgmer но так или иначе,мне еще рано лезть в android studio ?

Comment: xml не надо вы его быстро поймите.  Head first android недавно обновилась можно и ее. Но вот только издание 2018 года, а не старое

Comment: Откройте любой курс по андроиду, если вы не понимаете, что происходит и как все работает, то рано

Comment: @Valgaal а как на счет закрепления полученной информации ? Теория то одно, а практика -  то уже другое. Или тех примеров, что в книге, будет достаточно,чтобы подробно разобраться ?

Comment: Делайте свои примеры конечно. Я делал примеры из книги и курсов со своими доработками

Comment: @Valgaal вы говорите, что прочитали книгу где-то за месяц,т.е. вы каждый день читали новые темы? не делали, к примеру, в первый день прочитали, второй день закрепили ? (Блин,столько вопросов в голове.. Так не хватает наставника, который бы направлял в нужное русло )

Comment: Нет, я ничего не закреплял, мне же не к экзамену готовиться. У меня была цель сделать несколько приложений к такому-то числу. Я прошел курсы, сделал примеры, а потом сделал свои приложения

Comment: @Valgaal с вами можно еще пообщаться вне этого сайта ?) а то у нас уже прям дискуссия началась :D (Телеграмм, вк)

Comment: У меня, к сожалению, сейчас нет времени что-то объяснять. Все, что нужно я написал выше. Лучше, когда вы всю информацию сами будете искать, особенно в андроиде. Пусть вашим наставником лучше будет Jake Wharton.

Comment: @Valgaal так или иначе, большое спасибо за совет ! Очень помогли мне разобраться в своих мыслях и заблуждениях о том, " как лучше изучать ". Теперь у меня есть четкий план - прочитать книгу, которую вы посоветовали, после прочтения переходить к изучению android разработки(Startandroid) и изучению нужных библиотек :)

Comment: @Влад насчет того, что не читать ничего позднее 2016 года - это конечно не верно. Да, Android развивается и появляются новые возможности, но **они добавляются**, а не заменяются. В основе разработки лежит все то же, что и 10 лет назад. Начав изучать самое свежее, вы напротив больше запутаетесь в большом объеме, чем получите какие то выгоды от пропущенного опыта , накопленного за прошлые годы, к тому же раньше все было в разы проще. не стоит сразу бросаться во все эти даггеры, RX технологии, MVP-паттерны и прочий мрак ..

Answer (score 10):

Приведу пример: вы можете прочитать все книги о том, как правильно ездить на
велосипеде. Вы даже можете посмотреть несколько видеороликов о том, как люди
ездят на велосипеде. Я мог бы прочитать лекцию о том, как правильно ездить на велосипеде, но, если вы никогда не ездили сами, вы упадете, как только сядете на
велосипед в первый раз. Вы можете знать о велосипедах все — и как правильно
ездить, и какие модели самые лучшие, но вы никогда не научитесь ездить на велосипеде, пока не примените знания на практике.
Почему же тогда многие разработчики берут книгу по языку программирования
или фреймворку и читают ее от корки до корки, надеясь впитать всю информацию?
В лучшем случае вы соберете всю информацию по теме, но не выучите ее. (с) Джон Сонмез, Путь программиста

Узнайте достаточно чтобы начать и действуйте

Comment: спасибо за совет !

Comment: пример в цитаты!

Answer (score 3):

В общем то все просто. Чтобы начать изучать фреймворк Android вы должны сносно читать и понимать Java-код, принципы ООП, основные паттерны в Java (в частности интерфейс обратного вызова очень часто используется в Android) и тп. Иначе все примеры по разработке будут для вас непонятны, так как практически все материалы по Android объясняют особенности работы с самим фреймворком, а не реализующий их Java-код.

Не понимая написанного кода, вы сможете что то повторять, копипастить, но не писать свой код. На чужом же коде далеко не уйдешь.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO ни в коем случае нельзя начинать изучать программирование с Java. Испортите себе мышление на всю жизнь. Изучите сначала какой-нибудь традиционный язык: Паскаль или С.

Создатель stackoverflow.com считает также: http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Java